# Errors while compiling C++ file including LLVM API headers

Tags: c++, llvm

#### Hello,

I have installed `llvm` and `llvm-debuginfo` using `apt install` and am trying to compile this file:

llvm_test.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/Support/SourceMgr.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   if( argc < 2 )
      llvm::errs() << "Expected an argument - IR file name\n";

   llvm::LLVMContext &context = llvm::getGlobalContext();
   llvm::SMDiagnostic err;
   llvm::Module* module = llvm::ParseIRFile( argv[1], err, context );

   if( !mod )
   {
      err.print( argv[0], errs() );
      return 1;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Using following command:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 llvm_test.cpp `llvm-config --system-libs --cppflags --ldflags --libs core` -o llvm_test
```

But it doesn't seem to find required API headers. This is the error message:

```
llvm_test.cpp:9:13: error: no member named 'errs' in namespace 'llvm'
  llvm::errs() << "Expected an argument - IR file name\n";
      ~~~~~~^
llvm_test.cpp:11:39: error: no member named 'getGlobalContext' in namespace
      'llvm'
   llvm::LLVMContext &context = llvm::getGlobalContext();
                                ~~~~~~^
llvm_test.cpp:13:33: error: no member named 'ParseIRFile' in namespace 'llvm'
   llvm::Module* module = llvm::ParseIRFile( argv[1], err, context );
                          ~~~~~~^
llvm_test.cpp:15:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mod'
   if( !mod )
        ^
llvm_test.cpp:17:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'errs'
      err.print( argv[0], errs() );
                      ^
5 errors generated.
```

Adding "support" to llvm-config arguments, as suggested in comments, doesn't change anything: same errors.

#### What is wrong with this?

Note: I am using Cygwin on Windows and I meant apt-cyg (apt like tool for Cygwin) under apt.

Comment: `apt` suggests that you are using the linux subsystem for windows, but later you said cygwin. Which is the case?

Comment: `llvm::errs()` is in the support sublibrary, can you change `--libs core` to  `--libs core support` and see if that gets you any further?

Comment: What version of LLVM are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) error: no member named 'errs' in namespace 'llvm'

You must include: `#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"`

2) error: no member named 'getGlobalContext' in namespace

It is due to getGlobalContext was removed after llvm 3.6. So use: `LLVMContext context;`  and give a reference of it where required.

3) error: no member named 'ParseIRFile' in namespace 'llvm'

You must include: `#include "llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h"`

4)error: use of undeclared identifier 'mod'

Use `module` instead of mod in here

Answer (score 3):

If you need `errs`, you should include the right header:

```
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
```

`ParseIRFile` should be in `llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h`

```
#include "llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h"
```